# Drawing arrow without filling

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I draw an arrow which is empty inside and only has a border?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], 
  ChartElementData["ArrowRectangle", "TaperRatio" -> 0, 
    "ArrowWidth" -> 0.6, "ArrowheadAngle" -> 120][{{0, .2}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Play with different option values (`"TaperRatio"`, `"ArrowWidth"` and `"ArrowheadAngle"`) and bounding box horizontal and vertical ranges (`{0,.2}` and `{0,1}`, respectively, in the example above) to get different shapes.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help @kglr